# Windows 'findstr' command: Exclude results containing particular string

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

To the command `findstr str1 *.*` I want to add something that will exclude the results which contain the string `str2`.

In Linux the way of doing it is to add `| grep -v str2` (to `grep str1 *` of course). Is there an equivalent flag to `-v`  in Windows?

Comment: I typed `findstr /?` into the command window and saw `/V Prints only lines that do not contain a match.`

Comment: Thanks. You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent flag to `-v` in Windows?

The equivalent to `-v` is `/V`.

```
C:\Users\Todd>findstr /?
Searches for strings in files.

...

/V         Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
```

Comment: while it says `/V` in the help text, you are allowed to use both `-` instead of `/` and `v` instead of `V`, so `-v` does already do the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

use `/V`, for example: `findstr "hello world" *.cpp | findstr /V ".git\\"`

Comment: Wow! I just discovered you need the double backslash, `".git\"` doesn't work. The only downside is, the filenames are not highlighted anymore :( I now have a replacement of `wcgrep`, by using `findstr /S "needle" * | findstr /V "..."`